# How should 'God' in 2 Cor 13:14 be understood?

Tags: 2-corinthians

> The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God, and the
> fellowship of the Holy Spirit, be with you all.

If God includes the Son and the Spirit, it's odd that Paul chose to express his encouragement that way?

It seems analogous to saying Jesus, Father , Son, Spirit and Spirit

Comment: You need to ask this question on Stack Exchange - Christianity which deals with comparative religion (who believes what). This is an hermeneutic site which examines the text of scripture (what do the words mean). This question needs to be migrated but I think the question will already have been answered in SE-C, in the archives. The Greek word _Theos_ means 'God' or 'Deity'.

Comment: Eve, obviously, was **not** Adam (meaning *human*); does this therefore mean that women are inhuman, and should be classified as an entirely different species altogether ?

Answer (score 3):

Let us be clear about what we are discussing here.  The word "God" θεός (theos) occurs in various ways throughout the NT.  In 2 Cor 13:14 (in English Bibles but 2 Cor 13:13 in Greek NA28 etc) occurs with the article, in this case τοῦ Θεοῦ the genitive form of ὁ Θεός.

In many ὁ Θεός refers to God generally, that is, the entire Godhead but quite often it refers to the Father such as in Matt 3:9, 5:8, 34, etc.

Sometimes, ὁ Θεός refers to Jesus Himself such as in Matt 1:23, John 20:28, Heb 1:8.

The difference is usually easy to spot (in most cases) and 1 Cor 13:14 is one that is not difficult.  ὁ Θεός here means the Father because we have God (the Father) in contradistinction from the Son and the Spirit.